# How to enable Auto-Capitalization in Keyboard Setting of the iPAD devices in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, uppercase

I investigated to enable item Auto-Capitalization to use upper-case characters in app. I searched the related permission in Info.plist file. But it didn't has any settings.

In Xamarin.Forms (iOS), could we enable item Auto-Capitalization (Go to Setting -> General -> Keyboard) which was disable on the iPAD device? Or What customize to show confirm message to allow enable it?

[image]

Comment: umm in my knowledge its not possible!

Comment: `Entry` now have autocapitalisation enability on a entry level. [see site](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1833)